# Markov Chains - Transition Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm trying to understand how the transition matrix is supposed to look like. I assigned the first row to be H, then M then L and assigned values given the data. But this seems to be incorrect, any suggestions?

any assistance on the other questions will be appreciated also

Answer (score 1):

Your rows should sum up to $1$, you want to change your diagonal entries to be $1$ minus the sum of the off-diagonal entries along that row.

For example, $A_{11} = 1- A_{12}- A_{13}$.

Comment: i got the matrix right after trying a couple of different combinations thanks! just having trouble with the subsequent questions though!

Comment: can you describe what you have tried and what difficulty do you face?